# how to compare login time and logout time.logout time must greater than login time using timepicker

Tags: c#, .net, timepicker

```
if (Convert.ToDateTime(GrdEmployeeAttendance.CurrentRow.Cells["LoginTime"].Value) < Convert.ToDateTime(GrdEmployeeAttendance.CurrentRow.Cells["LogoutTime"].Value))
{
    if (GrdEmployeeAttendance.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "LoginTime")
    {
        GrdEmployeeAttendance.EndEdit();

        if (Convert.ToDateTime(GrdEmployeeAttendance.CurrentRow.Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value) < Convert.ToDateTime("01:00 PM"))
        {
            GrdEmployeeAttendance.CurrentRow.Cells["CheckFN"].Value = true;
        }
        else
        {
            GrdEmployeeAttendance.CurrentRow.Cells["ChkAN"].Value = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What you mean by this what exactly you need please edit and provide more input the appropriate one as per you needed

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Just a couple of hints. You need to explain to us what you wish to accomplish, and/or what the issue is that you are facing. try to be as clear as possible, as this will enable us to help you quicker. Failing to do so will have the other users close this question, without any benefit to you.

Comment: Aswathi, this is your third extremely lazy question. If you want help, take the time to ask a question, not just copy & paste your code. I took the time to answer your last question and you did not mark it as an aswer. I will not help you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compare the login time to the logout time, you will want to use the **[`DateTime.Compare` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare.aspx)**.

It takes two arguments (the two instances of a `DateTime` object to be compared), and returns an integer that indicates whether the first is earlier than, the same as, or later than the second.

If the first time is earlier, the return value will be less than 0. If the two time values are the same, the return value will be 0. If the first time is later, the return value will be greater than zero.

Sample code:

```
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2009, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0);
DateTime date2 = new DateTime(2009, 8, 1, 12, 0, 0);
int result = DateTime.Compare(date1, date2);
string relationship;

if (result < 0)
   relationship = "is earlier than";
else if (result == 0)
   relationship = "is the same time as";         
else
   relationship = "is later than";

Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", date1, relationship, date2);

// The example displays the following output:
//    8/1/2009 12:00:00 AM is earlier than 8/1/2009 12:00:00 PM
```